# List original declared scopes for dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependency-management

I'd like to programmatically list all scopes where given dependency was declared.

For example having in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    runtime "commons-io:commons-io:2.5"
}
```

I'd like to have information that `commons-io:commons-io:2.5` has `runtime` scope.

However, if I create the following task:

```
task runtimeDeps << {
    configurations.findByName('runtime').allDependencies.each { println it }
}
```

I'm getting output:

```
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='commons-io', name='commons-io', version='2.5', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='junit', name='junit', version='4.12', configuration='default'}
```

Which is too much, as `junit` was declared with `compile`. **How can I acquire information about the original scope of dependency?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `allDependencies` use `dependencies`:

```
task runtimeDeps << {
    configurations.findByName('runtime').dependencies.each { println it }
}
```

`allDependencies` returns dependencies also for scope that `runtime` extends, namely `compile`.